# Grails refresh chart

Tags: grails, morris.js

I'm using a morris.js pie chart in my grails project and now i try to count an int after a button click and refresh the chart. But if i use "redirect" it refresh the whole site.
So is there a recommended way to refresh only the chart?

gsp:

```
<g:form controller="blankTest">
    <g:actionSubmit value="Update" action="action"/>
</g:form>
<div id="myfirstchart" style="height: 250px;"></div>

<g:javascript id="test">
    new Morris.Donut({
        // ID of the element in which to draw the chart.
        element: 'myfirstchart',

        label: 'Test',

        resize: true,

        colors : ['#00ff00', '#ff0000', '#ffff00'],

        data: [
            { label: 'Number1', value: ${number}},
            { label: 'Number2', value: ${number1}},
            { label: 'Number3', value: ${number2}}
        ],
    });
</g:javascript>
```

Controller:

```
int number = 0

def index() {
    [number: number, number1: 34, number2: 8]
}

def action() {
    number++
    redirect view: 'index'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is creating a request by an ajax call, which will give you a response that you will use for updating your Morris donut.

So you could use your form for creating a ajax call. You have two options:

1. Using remote tags ([out of the box on 1.x and 2.x grails](http://docs.grails.org/2.2.1/ref/Tags/formRemote.html) versions, or with [remote tags plugin](http://plugins.grails.org/plugin/grails/ajax-tags) on grails 3.x. Using a remote form, you could update a piece of your html code with the response from an action, which renders a template.
2. Implementing your own ajax method, recommended for a well code implementation, cause a remote ajax grails tag appends js code on your HTML. It is not good at all (a front-end dev will kill you and a kitty cat also :) ), and is deprecated.

This ajax request has to return you a new data model, could be in a JSON format and you can update your donut with the method js [setData](https://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js/donuts.html).

```
<g:form name="form" controller="blankTest">
    <input type="submit" value="Update"/>
</g:form>
<div id="myfirstchart" style="height: 250px;"></div>

<g:javascript id="test">
    //we will need this reference for updating it
    var donut = new Morris.Donut({
        // ID of the element in which to draw the chart.
        element: 'myfirstchart',

        label: 'Test',

        resize: true,

        colors : ['#00ff00', '#ff0000', '#ffff00'],

        data: [
            { label: 'Number1', value: ${number}},
            { label: 'Number2', value: ${number1}},
            { label: 'Number3', value: ${number2}}
        ],
    });

$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#form').submit(function(event){
       event.preventDefault(); //blocks native form submit

       $.ajax('${createLink(controller: 'blankTest', action: 'action')}', {
           success: function (data) {
               var response = $.parseJSON(data);
               donut.setData(response); //updating the donut with json response
           }
       });
   });   

});
</g:javascript>
```

And your action should be something like this

```
def action() {
    number++
    List result = [
       [label: 'Number1', value: number],
       [label: 'Number2', value: number1],
       [label: 'Number3', value: number2]
    ]

    render result as JSON
}
```

For more complex JSON's consider use [JSON views](http://views.grails.org/latest/) if you are using Grails greater than v.3.1

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer it's really helpful. :) Think I have to work more with Ajax. I've tried your code and I've got an error in my browser console: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1". After I removed "var response = $.parseJSON(data);" it works. I think the result from the controller is already in JSON, so you don't have to parse it again. But I'm not sure. :)

Comment: You are welcome. The response its not a json by default in a controller, you have to parse it. Use the chrome debugger to know what data is on the success method.